# Аналитика изменения параметров oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Подскажите как лучше реализовать запрос.
Дана таблица на большое число строк:

| Article | Par1 | Editor | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | kg | Ivanov | 26.01.01 12:20 |
| Apple | mg | Sidorov | 25.01.01 13:01 |
| Apple | mg | Sidorov | 25.01.01 12:01 |
| Apple | ton | Ivanov | 24.01.01 11:01 |

Суть таблицы вывод изменений параметра одного из артикулов, кто его сделал, и дата операции.
Бывают строки (как у Sidorov), где был изменен другой параметр, может быть несколько одинаковых строк за разной датой. (У артикулов параметров много но контролировать нужно только один)

Мне нужно вывести только тех кто изменял этот параметр. То есть из прошлой таблицы нужно получить следующую:

| Article | Par1 | Editor | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | kg | Ivanov | 26.01.01 12:20 |
| Apple | mg | Sidorov | 25.01.01 12:01 |

Я попробовал использовать `LAG (Article,1) over (order by Article)`
Через Case получив 0 где не было изменений и 1 где было изменение. Но отсортировать и оставить только одного Sidorov не получается.. Что тут можно придумать?

Comment: А почему на выходе строки за 22 число ? какой критерий какую из строк брать. И на выходе у вас показано, что там должна остаться одна строка по editor. так ли это ?

Comment: @Mike сортировка по дате (исправил таблицу). То есть каждая следующая строка (снизу вверх) это какое то изменение которое надо выводить.  Если менялся другой параметр то в таблице будет две строки (как с одинаковым par1, так и с одинаковым или разным Editor). Которые надо фильтровать. То есть главное по чему надо делать сортировку это по изменению par1. Если менялся то выводим строку что выше (из двух).

Comment: Если par1 важен, то почему в результатах нет строки ton. И сейчас пример стал еще более не понятным потому что вы поменяли даты в теблице, но в примере результата осталось 22 число

Comment: @Mike Извиняюсь, исправил. Я вижу алгоритм так: начиная с первой строки (самой старой по дате), берем попарно строки где par1 отличается и сравниваем. В моем примере 4 строки. 1-2 параметр менялся, запоминаем, 2-3 параметр не менялся, выкидываем, 3-4 менялся. Итого остается 1-2 3-4, от сюда надо вывести только 2 и 4 строки

Comment: А почему тогда `LAG (Article,1) over (order by Article)` а не `LAG (par1,1) over (order by Article)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать LAG, как ты и хотел

```
select     
    Article, Par1, Editor, Date_
from
    (    
    select 
        Article, Par1, Editor, Date_, 
        case when Par1 <> lag (Par1) over (partition by Article order by Date_) then 1 end is_modified
    from     
        t
    )
where
    is_modified = 1         
order by 
    Date_ desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from(
    select Article, Par1, Editor, Date_, nvl(lag (Par1,1) over (order by Date_),0) as prev
    from
        (select Article, nvl(Par1,'null') as Par1, Date_, Editor from T)
        order by dzupd desc)
where Par1 <> prev
```

This code work for my task.